# Video rotation with FFmpeg

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, rotation

I'm developing a PHP web service for my iPhone app in order for the users to upload videos. When users want to see a video on the site they get a horizontal video,  so I need rotate the video using FFmpeg commands. Can someone help me?

```
function make_rotation($input, $output, $transpose="1") {
    $ffmpegpath = "ffmpeg";
    if(!file_exists($input)) return false;  
    //$command = "$ffmpegpath -i $input -vf 'transpose=$transpose' $output";
    //$command = "ffmpeg -vfilters 'rotate=270' -i $input $output";
    $command ="ffmpeg -i $input -vf 'transpose=$transpose'  $output";
    exec($command);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -vfilters "rotate=90" -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

above comment works for me, add "rotate=90" and check.

```
ffmpeg -i <input_video> -vf “transpose=1″ -r 30 -sameq <output_video>
```

also work

Comment: Hi KPBird many thanks...but can tell me here input file and output file are same or different..thanks again

Comment: @KPBird I did tried the second option to rotate my video but it doesn't rotate to 90 degree with 1, than I passed 2 it did rotate but 180 degree Please let me know what can be done.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the rotation issues with this mencode command like this way:

```
function make_rotation($input, $output, $transpose="1") {
    $cmd="mencoder -vf rotate=1 -o $output -oac pcm -ovc lavc $input";
    exec($cmd);
    if(!file_exists($output)) return false;
    if(filesize($output)==0) return false;
    return true;
}
```